# Rx Merge prevents initial value

Tags: system.reactive, reactive

I am new to Reactive development, and am having trouble combining multiple subjects in a way that will confer initial values as well as changes which occur on the subjects over time.

With the code below I expected:

```
first - OnNext(a)  <-- initial on subscribe
first - OnNext(c)  <-- initial on subscribe
first - OnNext(b)  <-- result of OnNext
second - OnNext(b) <-- initial on subscribe
second - OnNext(c) <-- initial on subscribe
first - OnNext(d)  <-- result of OnNext
second - OnNext(d) <-- result of OnNext
```

But I get:

```
first - OnNext(b)  <-- result of OnNext
first - OnNext(d)  <-- result of OnNext
second - OnNext(d) <-- result of OnNext
```

Code:

```
var connection1 = new BehaviorSubject<string>("a");
var connection2 = new BehaviorSubject<string>("c");
var connection = Observable.Merge(connection1, connection2).StartWith(connection1.Value, connection2.Value).Publish();
connection.Connect();
connection.SubscribeLogger("first");
connection1.OnNext("b");
connection.SubscribeLogger("second");
connection2.OnNext("d");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code appears to do what I wanted:

```
var subject1 = new BehaviorSubject<string>("a");
var subject2 = new BehaviorSubject<string>("c");
// Use separate merged observables to simulate multiple calls to getter
// under the hood which builds the new merged view of the subjects.
var connection = subject1.Merge(subject2);
var connection2 = subject1.Merge(subject2);

connection.SubscribeLogger("first");
subject1.OnNext("b");
connection2.SubscribeLogger("second");
subject2.OnNext("d");
```

Output:

```
first - OnNext(a)
first - OnNext(c)
first - OnNext(b)
second - OnNext(b)
second - OnNext(c)
first - OnNext(d)
second - OnNext(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) is a link that explains the general ideal behind a Connected Observable (created by the call to `Connect()` on the merged output.

When `Connect()` is called, the merged output sends its published values to subscribers (none at this point, so the initial `a` and `c` are sent to no subscribers.

Then `first` subscribes and the subsequent call to `connection1.OnNext("b");` causes the publishing of `b` which is displayed by the `first` subscriber.

Next, `second` subscribes, but because it is a Connected Observable, `second` will only receive values which are published after its subscription. So, the call to `connection2.OnNext("d");` gets published by the connected merged observable to its subscribers which are `first` and `second`.

It takes a bit of time and effort to understand the marble diagrams that usually are used to explain reactive operations. However, they offer a nice, graphical way to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very clear explanation. Which means I don't think what I want to do is possible.. I wanted to have a hot observable which could be listened to for future state change events (a composite of multiple subjects), but on subscription it would give current state. However, because hot observables have the shared events across all observers that would obviously be impossible.

Comment: The `Replay` operator may be what you're after. See http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#Replay

Answer (score 2):

If you change your code to this...

```
var connection1 = new BehaviorSubject<string>("a");
var connection2 = new BehaviorSubject<string>("c");
var connection = Observable.Merge(connection1, connection2).StartWith(connection1.Value, connection2.Value).Publish();
connection.SubscribeLogger("first"); //Flip order, put Subscribe before connect
connection.Connect();
connection1.OnNext("b");
connection.SubscribeLogger("second");
connection2.OnNext("d");
```

Then you'll get this output:

```
first - OnNext(a) //From the start with
first - OnNext(c) //From the start with
first - OnNext(a) //From the behavior subject
first - OnNext(c) //From the behavior subject
first - OnNext(b)
first - OnNext(d)
second - OnNext(d)
```

`Publish`/`Connect` transitions a cold observable to a hot observable. After you `Publish`, if you wanted to get any of the "on-subscribe" values, you need to subscribe then before connecting. After you `Connect`, none of the Cold or "on-subscribe" values will reach new subscribers.